# How to write a function that imputes missing numeric and character values?

Tags: r, imputation

I have the following sample data:

```
ID GLUC TGL HDL LDL HRT MAMM SMOKE

A   88   NA  32  99   Y   NA never

B   NA   150 60  NA  NA   no never

C   110   NA NA 120   N   NA    NA

D   NA   200 65 165  NA  yes never
```

I need to write a function that replaces missing numeric variables with the median value of the numeric variable. For a character variables, I need to replace the missing values with the value of the highest frequency of the character variable. The function takes two arguments, the name of the data frame and a character vector.

My desired result with the function below:

```
impute (dat=patient, varlist=c("LDL", "HRT", "MAMM"))
LDL HRT MAMM
 99   Y  yes
165   Y   no
120   N  yes
165   Y  yes
150   Y  yes
```

I have these variables written, but I'm struggling to put it together in a function.

```
patient$TGL[which(is.na(patient$TGL))] <- median(patient$TGL, na.rm=TRUE)
patient$TGL[which(is.na(patient$TGL))] <- which.max(patient$TGL, na.rm=TRUE)
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: you probably should have a look at `mice` package: https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to set values as you intended in your example with functions:

```
library(foreach)

patient = read.table(
  textConnection("ID GLUC TGL HDL LDL HRT MAMM SMOKE
A   88   NA  32  99   Y   NA never
B   NA   150 60  NA  NA   no never
C   110   NA NA 120   N   NA    NA
D   NA   200 65 165  NA  yes never"),  header = TRUE)

#' imputes vector values
impute_v <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    res <- median(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  else {
    res <- x[which.max(x)]
  }
  na.index <- which(is.na(x))
  x[na.index] <- res
  x
}

# returns imputed values for selected columns in a data frame
impute_df <- function(df, names) {
  foreach(name = names) %do% {
    df[, name] <- impute_v(df[, name])
  }
  df[, names]
}

impute_df(patient, names = c("LDL", "HRT", "MAMM"))
#    LDL HRT MAMM
# 1  99   Y  yes
# 2 120   Y   no
# 3 120   N  yes
# 4 165   Y  yes
```